# Is checking for null against a string in jQuery using two equals signs bad practice?

Tags: jquery, null, jslint, string

JSLint flags this:

```
if ($(stringToClean).html() == null)
```

...with the warning "*comparisons against null, 0, true, false, or an empty string allowing implicit type conversion (use === or !==)*"

My understanding is that if I had "===" it would only check for null itself, but if I have (as I do) "==" it would also check for things that are "nothing" such as an empty string.

If my assumption is correct, "==" may actually be desirable in many such cases, no?

Comment: I would rewrite the condition to simply `if($(stringToClean).html().length)`

Comment: Do you mean "if($(stringToClean).html().length === 0)" ?

Comment: what is your question? if `==` sometimes is desirable?

Comment: the html method never return null (it's undefined by the look of things) so I wouldn't suggest testing against it. Here a simple ```if (!$(stringToClean).html())``` would work the same.

Comment: there is a difference between "nothing", null and an empty string...

Comment: Don't test against ```length```, ```jQuery.html``` can return ```undefined``` which obviously doesn't have a ```length``` property. ```===``` is always safe way to go, but it wouldn't work in your case as ```html``` would need to return ```null```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `==` operator checks value, while the operator `===` checks value *and* type.

For example:

```
5 == "5" -> true

5 === "5" -> false
```

to understand `null`, it is necessary to consider `undefined` as well.

```
typeof(null) -> object

typeof(undefined) -> undefined
```

but

```
null == undefined -> true
```

In your example, let us suppose you try to invoke the `html()` method on a selector that does not have any matches:

```
$('#nonExistentDiv').html()
```

the result is `undefined`. This means that:

```
$('#nonExistentDiv').html() === null -> false

$('#nonExistentDiv').html() == null -> true
```

If you try with an existing but empty DIV element you get an empty string:

```
$('#emptyDiv').html() == null -> false
$('#emptyDiv').html() == 0 -> true (intresting!)
$('#emptyDiv').html() === "" -> true
```

So:

- if you want to check if a string is null you should use `if(myString == null)`.
- if you want to check if a string is empty `if(myString === "")`
- if you want to check if a string actually "contains something" you can check `if(myString)`